# Showing progress bar while loading a List

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-listview

Ok Now i admit that i am new to using progress bar infact i never use it but now i need to use it 
I have an activity (Main) and a menu which can start 6 new activity. From these activities there is an activity which load the data in a ListView it take 3-4 second to load .This activity parse the json and pass the data to another activity. How can i show the progress bar as soon as user click the menu option for this activity and disappear it when List will be loaded.

Here is the activiy

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     final Intent intent=new Intent(this ,GetLatAndLng.class);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
    //ProgressBar pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String context=Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
        updateWithNewLocation(null);
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
        Bundle extras){ }
        };
    updateWithNewLocation(location);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10,
            locationListener);
    double geoLat = location.getLatitute();
    double geoLng = location.getLongitude();
         Bundle b=new Bundle();
    //pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    JSONObject json = JSONFunction.getJSONfromURL(getUrl());
    Log.v(TAG, "got the json"); 
    try{
        JSONArray  JArray = json.getJSONArray("results");
           Log.v(TAG, "getting results");
        for(int i=0;i<JArray.length();i++){                     
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = JArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject location1=e.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
            latitude[i]=location1.getDouble("lat");
            longitude[i]=location1.getDouble("lng");
            reference[i]=e.getString("reference");
            Log.v(TAG, reference[i]);
            distance[i]=GetLatAndLng.gps2m(geoLat, geoLng,latitude[i] ,longitude[i]); 
            map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
            map.put("name", "" + e.getString("name"));
            map.put("vicinity", "Address " +  e.getString("vicinity")+" "+"Disance:"+distance[i]);

            mylist.add(map);                
        }           
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
//   pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    b.putStringArray("key", reference);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    Log.v(TAG, ""+reference); 
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.listview, 
                    new String[] { "name", "vicinity", }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {        
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
           Toast.makeText(JsonExampleActivity.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            intent.putExtra("clickedid",position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
public void updateWithNewLocation(Location location2) {
    if(location2!=null) {
          double geoLat = location2.getLatitude();
            double geoLng = location2.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `AsyncTask` to load data in background while showing loading indicator. In `AsyncTask's` `doInBackground` method , process the JSON or anything which is taking time.

```
public class HeavyWorker extends AsyncTask < String , Context , Void > {

    private ProgressDialog      progressDialog ;
    private Context             targetCtx ;

    public HeavyWorker ( Context context ) {
        this.targetCtx = context ;
        this.needToShow = true;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog ( targetCtx ) ;
        progressDialog.setCancelable ( false ) ;
        progressDialog.setMessage ( "Retrieving data..." ) ;
        progressDialog.setTitle ( "Please wait" ) ;
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate ( true ) ;
    }

    @ Override
    protected void onPreExecute ( ) {
        progressDialog.show ( ) ;
    }

    @ Override
    protected Void doInBackground ( String ... params ) {
      // Do Your WORK here

       return null ;
    }

    @ Override
    protected void onPostExecute ( Void result ) {
        if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss ( ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

In your Activity's `onCreate()` execute `AsyncTask`

```
new HeavyWorker().execute();
```

Comment: This causes `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager` on the `progressDialog.dismiss ( )` line when screen orientation changes while the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of operations, you should use `AsyncTask` with that you can show progress dialog , while it loads.

The [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) is pretty helpful. Look into the `onPostExecute()` method to figure out how to end any sort of progress bar you may have.

Hope it helps

Comment: ok i admit that i need asynkTask but can i pass data from asynkTask class to another activity? as i pass above.

Comment: Yes you can, in onPostExecute method, you can work UI operations and can pass the data to the other activity..

Answer (score 1):

You should do it with an AsyncTask and show a progress dialog in the onPreExecuteMethod and dismiss it on onPostExecute:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Object> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context context;
    public MyAsyncTask(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading", "Wait", true, true);
        pd.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        if(pd.isShowing())
            pd.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe it will help. I use BroadcastReceiver to update ListView in my app.

```
public static final String UPDATE_HISTORY_LIST = "com.myapp.update_history_list";
```

onPostExecute AsyncTask

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject par) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppSettings.UPDATE_HISTORY_LIST);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Receiver in Activity

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              Log.i(TAG, "Action: " + intent.getAction());
              if (AppSettings.UPDATE_HISTORY_LIST.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                  OrderHistoryFragment history = (OrderHistoryFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("history");
                  if(history != null && history.isVisible()){
                      history.refresh();
                  }
              }
          }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager lbm = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(AppSettings.UPDATE_HISTORY_LIST);
        lbm.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, filter);
    }
```

Layout

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
```

Activity

```
mList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
mList.setEmptyView(rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.progress));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that adding a property to your Activity:

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
```

Then just use this code to show your dialog:

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Title", "Loading", true);
```

And then add this when you want to delete it:

```
if(dialog!= null && dialog.isShowing())
   dialog.dismiss();
```

Also add to your onStop those lines (just in case the user exists the Activity):

```
public void onStop()
{
    if(dialog!= null && dialog.isShowing())
       dialog.dismiss();
    super.onStop();
}
```